# Flash Builder 4.7 Crashes on Mavericks: Finder & ADL

Tags: macos, air, adobe, flash-builder, osx-mavericks

As the title states, anytime I use flash builder to open a Finder dialog to search for files, Flash Builder crashes. It is very consistent. In more detail, when trying to link to an SWC or other project file Flash Builder (FB) tries to open a nonexistent folder on the file system (see image below). After FB fails to open a file once, the second time the prompt is opened the program crashes (if the prompt even opens).

The ADL (the device simulator) is also very buggy now. When left alone for a few minutes after running a test the next test often fails. Seems to be hanging.

Things I have done to attempt to fix the issue:

- I have uninstalled FB 4.7 and reinstalled.
- Attempted to use Flash Builder in freshly installed form.
- Updated Java (JDK) to most recent version
- Configured using AIR 3.4, 3.9, 4.0
- I have changed Finder to open to a different directory instead of seeing 'All my
  files'.

Screenshot of what Flash Builder tries to do before it crashes. Searching for swc's in a non-existant folder? Is there some way to change this folder? I have tried changing workplaces.
[image]

Screenshot of ADL after debugging several times. Have to force close it each time.
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Could not find a solution yet.

Comment: This seems to be a OSX issue. I have the same issue with Android Monitor app. Still investigating...

Comment: This documented eclipse bug seems to describe the problem: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=420682

Comment: I have not @tamak. With the Yosemite update the issue persists as well.